# How can i Modify identity user tables on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ef-code-first, fluent, ef-model-builder

I have created an Web Appplication project on Visual Studio and it has created some default tables for my database like UserRoles-Claims etc.

How can i modify them to change their PK or the attributes they hold.

I tried using Fluent API but i could only access the Application User table